# can we implement table splitting in grails/using Hibernate based on month in a date field

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, sharding

I have a huge transaction table which I need to split. Right now  am thinking on monthly basis. But I want this to be handled automatically by grails or by hibernate. It is similar to Sharding where a new table would be created  and data belonging to a month will be inserted in that months table. whenever I give a select query with a date range, the appropriate months are queried and data is retrieved. 
It would differ from the classical Sharding in that there is no limit on the data in each table and separation is based only on the month index.
I saw that there is a  grails Sharding plugin, but it looks like it is used for something different?

Right now I have created this structure of 12 tables manually and for every select I get the date range and get a list of month domains to query on and retrieve individually and then again combine this data..

I want to know if I am not using something out of the box instead of doing the whole implementation manually

Thanks in advance
Priyank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention which database you're using.

Sounds like a lot like table partitioning, supported by databases like [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/options/partitioning/index.html) and [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/ddl-partitioning.html).

This kind of feature is best implemented within the database and hidden from the application. For example test systems rarely need partitioned tables.

**Update:**

Googling also found a [sharding plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/sharding) for grails, with [article](http://jeffrick.com/2010/07/13/a-grails-plugin-for-sharding/) describing its use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply..I dont mind having partitions in database as long as its supported by almost all types and just a difference in schema creation script. I also read about the sharding plugin, but it looks like its used for having totally diferent schemas in one application based on users.. not sure though.. I want to make it generic hence implementing it in hibernate would be the best way, if there is such a feture.

Comment: Yeah, not all databases support table partitioning. Still think it's your best option. Target your large installations to use Oracle or Postgres. Develop test systems on other DBs. There is a Hibernate shards subproject. No idea if Grails supports it (http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/shards.html)